# Recursive models are not loaded using find('all') or read(null, id) in cake shells

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, model, batch-file

I cannot get access to recursive models in my cakephp shell.

The data of MyModel are loaded, but joins are not performed. When using the same MyModel and associations from a controller, joins are performed and data is loaded.

Does anybody experienced this problem ?

Comment: I solved the problem and posted the question/answer for sharing knowledge. Code available in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was comming from the $uses I was using:

In controller I had:

```
$uses = array('MyPlugin.MyModel');
```

In shell I had:

```
$uses = array('MyModel');
```

Cakephp was able to find the model even without reference to the plugin, but it failed to find HABTM ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can set $recursive to different values based on the amount of data you want.Imagine your application features Groups which belong to a domain and have many Users which in turn have many Articles.Then

```
Depth   Description
-1       Cake fetches Group data only, no joins.
0        Cake fetches Group data and its domain
1        Cake fetches a Group, its domain and its associated Users
2        Cake fetches a Group, its domain, its associated Users, and the Users' associated Articles
```

Set it no higher than you need. Having CakePHP fetch data you aren’t going to use slows your app unnecessarily. Also note that the default recursive level is 1.